# Execute immediate within context of a sql udf

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to use [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) from within a SQL udf? It's a very cool feature, but it seems it can only be called from within a SQL procedure, and BigQuery doesn't allow a stored procedure to be called within a SQL udf if I'm understanding properly.

Is this possible to do somehow in a SQL function, as I'm trying to dynamically build a query using the execute immediate command.

Comment: maybe you can present some practical example to narrow down "thinking process"?  :o)